# How to input chapters without newpage?

Tags: formatting

I have a following problem. In my main .tex I use this code:

```latex
%-----<<< MAIN MATTER >>>-----
\mainmatter                                                     %start arabic pagination from 1
\autohdr                                                                                %automatic headers for main matter
\input{02_Mainmatter/01_Intro.tex}              %input field
\input{02_Mainmatter/02.tex}
\input{02_Mainmatter/03.tex}
\input{02_Mainmatter/04.tex}
\input{02_Mainmatter/05.tex}
\input{02_Mainmatter/99_Concl.tex}
\clearpage
%-----<<< -------- >>>-----
```

The problem is that each chapter starts on a new page. Look:

[image]

How can I make every chapter to start below the last chapter? Without blank spaces? Thanks a lot.

EDIT:
I tried to change `\chapter` to `\section` but it totally destroyed my content:
[image]

EDIT2:
Here is the whole code:

```latex
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% thesis.tex -- MAIN FILE (the one that you compile with LaTeX)
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% version 1.8.09.02.16 (beta)

%-----<<<<<<<<<<<< START >>>>>>>>>>>>-----
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{report}                   
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{texcomp}   
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}     


                                            %for Czechoslovak characters

%-----<<<<<<<<<<<< STYLES >>>>>>>>>>>>-----                                                             
\usepackage{Styles/Head}
\usepackage{Styles/Mystyle} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{comment}


%-----<<< --------------------------------- >>>-----



%-----<<<<<<<<<<<< DOCUMENT >>>>>>>>>>>>-----
\begin{document}
\frontmatter                                                    %lowercase roman pagination for front matter
\clubpenalty 9999                                                           %not so many orphants
\widowpenalty 9999                                                          %not so many widows

%-----<<< HEAD >>>-----
\pagestyle{empty}                                       %no visible pagination here 
           


%-----<<< TABLE OF CONTENTS >>>-----
\pagestyle{fancy}                                                           %headers style
\fancyhead[LO]{\sffamily Contents}                          %headers in sans serif and not in uppercase
\phantomsection                                                                 %bookmark anchor
\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{toc}                          %add bookmark
\tableofcontents
\label{toc}
%\clearpage
%-----<<< ----------------- >>>-----



%-----<<< MAIN MATTER >>>-----
\mainmatter                                                     %start arabic pagination from 1
%\autohdr   

\input{02_Mainmatter/01_Intro.tex}              %input field
\input{02_Mainmatter/02.tex}
\input{02_Mainmatter/03.tex}
\input{02_Mainmatter/04.tex}
\input{02_Mainmatter/05.tex}
\input{02_Mainmatter/99_Concl.tex}
\clearpage
%-----<<< -------- >>>-----


%-----<<< REFERENCES >>>-----
\fancyhead[LO]{\sffamily Bibliography}                  %headers in sans serif and not in uppercase
\bibliographystyle{Styles/Stylebib}                         %style of literature, you can use e.g. newapa   instead of Styles/Stylebib
\bibliography{Styles/Bibliography}                          %bibliography database
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}        %Add bibliography to the table of contents
\clearpage
%-----<<< ---------- >>>-----

%-----<<< LIST OF TABLES >>>-----
\fancyhead[LO]{\sffamily List of Tables}                %headers in sans serif and not in uppercase
\phantomsection                                                                 %bookmark anchor
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}  %add LofT to the Table of Contents
\listoftables
\clearpage
%-----<<< --------------- >>>-----

%-----<<< LIST OF FIGURES >>>-----  
\fancyhead[LO]{\sffamily List of Figures}
\phantomsection                                                                 %bookmark anchor
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} %add LofF to the Table of Contents
\listoffigures
\clearpage
%-----<<< ---------------- >>>-----


%-----<<< APPENDIXES >>>-----
\backmatter                                                                         %uppercase roman pagination for back matter; appendices start
\autohdr                                                                                %automatic headers                  
\input{03_Backmatter/01_App.tex}                    %input file                     %input file

\clearpage

\end{document}
%-----<<<<<<<<< END OF DOCUMENT >>>>>>>>>-----
```

Comment: that is unrelated to `\input`, in most document classes `\chapter` headings are defined to start a page, but that depends on the docuemnt class which you have not shown

Comment: simpler would be to use a different document class with `\section` as the top level not chapter

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for your answer, see my edit please.

Comment: you have still not shown any relevant code.  you have 0. in front of the section numbers because you are using a book-level document class that numbers sections within chapters. If you used an article-level document class eg `\documentclass{article}` then `\section `is  the top level and you have no 0. and no page break.  But you have not provided any information about your document so impossible to say what to change.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle see my last edit, please

Comment: as I say use `\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{article}` instead of `\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{report}` unrelated but are you really using the legacy 8 bit encoding `\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}`  most editors, and latex and this site all default to UTF-8 these days.

Comment: Maybe add the option `openany` to the report class. I know that it works in book and memoir, but I don't remember if it is defined in report

Answer (score 0):

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report`, and when using the `article` option, `article` classes.

```
\documentclass[article,...]{memoir}
...
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}  % typesets as a section
  \section{Alpha} % typesets as a subsection
... and so on
\end{document}
```